# How to characterize "pointer" argument to createIndex in PyQt/PySide?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

It is common in PyQt/PySide to create indices using QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.createIndex(row, col, pointer). [In the PySide documentation](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QAbstractItemModel.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.createIndex) this method is described as follows:

> PySide.QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.createIndex(row, column, ptr)
>
> Creates a model index for the given row and column with the internal
>   pointer ptr

My question is what the third parameter means in Python, given that Python does not actually use pointers? Here is a typical example of the method in use (in this case in a method that returns the index of a parent node, given the child node's index):

```
def parent(self, index):
    childItem = index.internalPointer()
    parentItem = childItem.parent()
    return self.createIndex(parentItem.row(), 0, parentItem)
```

While we use `internalPointer()` to extract the child item, this is not the third input to `createIndex()` [edit: and even if it were, since it is python it would not be a pointer, for reasons in the next paragraph]. Rather, the third input to `createIndex()` is simply the parent item (not a pointer to the parent item). So it seems I am not feeding it a pointer at all, but simply another object that I have extracted with the help of a method called `internalPointer`.

Is the third input to `createIndex` really a pointer (as per the documentation)? Or should we just call it an item and eliminate talk of pointers?

---

Note this question is based on the `simpletreemodel` example that comes packaged with PySide ([documentation for Qt version](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-simpletreemodel.html)). The module `simpletreemodel.py` is located in `\PySide\examples\itemviews\simpletreemodel`.

I posted a version of this question at QtCentre:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/59747-Is-third-input-to-createIndex-really-a-pointer

Answer (score 2):

Don't take the `pointer` in the name as a literal 'C pointer'. As explained in the [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmodelindex.html#internalPointer), it's "used by the model to associate the index with the internal data structure". So given an `QModelIndex` you should be able to map that to the internal structure. For that purpose, `internalPointer` can be anything that helps you to do that. It's especially necessary in tree models, since `row` and `column` by themselves cannot fully identify an item in a hierarchical model.

Comment: yes, internalpointer seems pretty clear. And of the createIndex, what to make of the third argument, called a pointer in the doc (because of translation from C++)? Just another object, no? My concern is partly with the documentation that I quoted, which seems a bit misleading, probably because it was simply ported from C++.

Comment: @neuronet: Third argument to `createIndex` _is_ `internalPointer`.

Comment: Avaris as in my example it typically isn't directly `internalPointer`, but something derived from the class returned by the call to `internalPointer` (like a parent of the node returned by `internalpointer` method).

Comment: @neuronet: You're misinterpreting the example. That is creating an index for the `parent` from a `child`. In that setup, `internalPointer` is used to point to the underlying item (whatever that is). And that `item` has a `parent` method that returns the parent item. The parent index is constructed using `parentItem` as `internalPointer`.

Comment: In other words, the example is setup such that `index.internalPointer()` will give you the `item` that's associated with the `index`. I assume the `item` is a custom class with methods such as `parent` to let you navigate the data structure.

Comment: yes your previous comment is correct. So 'internalPointer' is a misnomer to some degree, and the third input to createIndex is not well described in the PySide/PyQt documentation (which it directly and automatically takes from Qt). Still working through all this, will have a response to myself in a year or so, at this rate :)

Comment: The name "pointer" is not brilliant. But it is not the item. It is data that your method can use to find the data for the item.  If you have an "item" object for each position in the tree then using that as the internalPointer is a reasonable idea.  But for file system (for example) then you want some kind of reference to the file.  Which could be a file name with path (for example).